# Choosing a Host for websites

Tags: wordpress, hosting, moodle

Can a wordpress domain and a moodle project be hosted by same provider, and what is important to weigh when comparing hosts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both wordpress and moodle uses PHP and MySQL, these are the most important things you would need on your host.